# Array to string conversion error when indexing array

Tags: php, arrays

It says I'm getting these errors:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Team_Aveera_Website\inc\user_functions.php on line 19
>   Array Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Team_Aveera_Website\inc\user_functions.php on line 22

When I try to index my array. What I'm doing is getting all rows from a database and adding a value from the row to an array. Then I get a random object from the array:

```
<?php
    function getRandomAdminStream($db) {
        try {
            $twitchNames[] = array();

            $SQL = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users');
            $SQL->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $SQL->execute();

            $i = 0;
            while($row = $SQL->fetch() !== FALSE) {
                if($row['rank'] == 1) {
                    $twitchNames[$i] = $row['twitchUsername'];
                    $i++;
                }
            }

            $random = $twitchNames[rand(0, count($twitchNames) - 1)];
            echo $random;

            echo '<iframe id="home-stream" type="text/html" height="420"
                src="http://www.twitch.tv/'.$random.'/embed"
                frameborder="0"></iframe>
                <div class="info-holder">
                </div>';
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: it shuld be print_r($random);

Comment: That doesnt make a difference, it just prints this: 'Array ( ) '

Comment: it makes a difference. do that

Comment: So what does `$random` contain? Looks like it _should_ contain a string, the `twitchUsername` atrribute. But if that is the case I do not understand where the notice comes from...

Comment: $random apparently contains Array()

Comment: What's the value you were getting within $row just print that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I set the fetch mode:

```
$SQL->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It still wouldnt use an associative array in the while loop, so I had to change the statement like so:

```
while($row = $SQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {}
```

Comment: so you got the solution.isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I managed to figure it out :)

Comment: Can i gave you explanation why you need to do that and why i posted below answer?

Comment: `print_r` prints a human-readable description about the variable. That is not what I needed to do, I needed to get the variable out of the array.

Because I was only inserting multiple columns into a single object reference, it would only return the empty array. Therefore I needed to fetch all the columns into an associative array where each column name refers to a specific value.

Comment: great you know all. but by seeing my code you won't get that. thanks.